# Run auto mail with timer on MVC Web Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a mvc web project. Now it is working on IIS. I want to do auto-mail service. Sql table has "targetDate, eMail, topicTxt" (DateTime). Programming logic is:

> if targetDate has passed send alert email with topicTxt to eMail

I did that inside controller. But it isn't working if no one isn't online.

I'm searching that:

> Even if there are no people online, Scan the information in the
>   database and If the required conditions are met: **send e-mails**

Can you sugget something about this issue.

Comment: You need to do some research for background jobs. I know that they can be implemented in such a web project. Or you use a service like uptimerobot.com calling one of your service end points regularly. I think a windows service has its advantages (but also more complexity) but a background job can do it too. I recommend reading this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks your reply. I'll research them especially azure webjobs..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing that in the Web app, You should probably write a windows service which runs all the time. Inside the service you can periodically( You can setup a timer which fires on a regular interval( Ex: every 5 minutes)) check your condition and do emailing part.

Here is a link to get started. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks your advice. I thought this solution but we'll move project in web host in a very short time. If i choose your suggest, i need a server 7/24. it will be high cost for me.